# rebot command running in Gitlab-CI return ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

Tags: python, automation, gitlab, cicd

My job running this command:

```
- rebot -d ./output/$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA 
  --doc "Report Testing Stage on execution summit ID $CI_COMMIT_SHA" 
  --output testing-stage.xml 
  --log log-testing-stage.html 
  --report report-testing-stage.html 
  ./output/$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA/*.xml
```

The output reports  ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
[Loggin Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWtzW.png)

Please let me know how to make the job run successfully. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `script` section of the `gitlab-ci` job, add an `echo` to make sure the [GitLab variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) is indeed replaced with the correct value (see [this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-ci-predefined-variable-ci-commit-before-sha-sometime-returns-all-zero-output/48177) for illustration)

```yaml
  stage: info
  script:
    - echo ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
    - echo ${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}
    - rebot -d ./output/${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}
      --doc "Report Testing Stage on execution summit ID ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}" 
      --output testing-stage.xml 
      --log log-testing-stage.html 
      --report report-testing-stage.html 
      ./output/${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}/*.xml
```

Use the `${var}` form instead of `$var`.

And finally, check the logs `log-testing-stage.html` content for any clues.